# JQuery Deferred rejection

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to do this:

```
sendDetails(formData).done(checkErrors).done(nextForm);
```

Where sendDetails returns a JQuery.ajax(...) object

and checkErrors for now is

```
function checkErrors(data) {
    $.Deferred().reject();
}
```

I was under the assumption that this would prevent the call to nextForm, but it doesn't - what am I missing?

Using jQuery 1.11

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16335597/jquery-deferred-cancel-progress

Answer (score 0):

The documentation here at http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/ says:

Since deferred.done() returns the deferred object, other methods of the deferred object can be chained to this one, including additional .done() methods.

If I understand your question, I think that answers your question. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery deferred: cancel progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16335597/jquery-deferred-cancel-progress) has the answer.
Basically .done returns a deferred object, not a promise, so you can't cancel the subsequent call from the first call.

```
sendDetails(formData).then(checkErrors).done(nextForm);
```

works as anticipated